# field.setInt() with annotations - java

Tags: java, annotations, field

EDITED:

OK, so say I have annotations `@X` and `@Y`

```
public class MyExampleClass{
  @X @Y Integer myfield;
}
```

The problem I am having is that when I call

```
field.setInt(o, new Integer(65)));
```

I get an error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Integer field MyExampleClass.myfield to (int)65
```

This is how field is initialized:

```
Field field = o.getClass().getField(fieldname);
```

`o` is an `Object` parameter. When I call it, I pass it an object of type `MyExampleClass`, and the value of `fieldname` is `"myfield"`.

Here is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Integer field MyExampleClass.myfield to (int)65
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Integer field MyExampleClass.myfield to (int)65
        at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(
UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
        at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(
UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:191)
        at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.setInt(UnsafeObjectFieldAcc
essorImpl.java:114)
        at java.lang.reflect.Field.setInt(Field.java:943)
        at MyCallingClass.get(MyCallingClass.java:111)
        at MyTester.main(MyTester.java:20)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An object does not have annotations. A field, class, method, etc. (see the `@Target` annotation) can be annotated, but the concept of annotated object does not exist. Annotations are just meta data. And they are constants.

What you are asking for is not possible.

Comment: When I run my program, I get the error:
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Integer field MyExampleClass.myfield to (int)56` 
If this isn't a problem with annotations, what would it be? It only happens when I use the setInt method.

Comment: @user3475234 Please post all relevant details in your question. I don't know what you are doing to help you.

Comment: @user3475234 And please include the full stack trace.

Comment: @user3475234 It seems that with `setInt`, the underlying field has to be of the primitive type `int`. Try using `set`.

Comment: Thank you, changing it to `set` worked. I figured Java would do its automatic conversions between `int` and `Integer` but it didn't. Thanks!

Comment: @user3475234 It's not entirely clear from the javadoc, but the `setX` methods seem to be used only for primitive types.